# caesar cipher Simple Encryption code in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caesar's Cipher using python, could use a little help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538935/caesars-cipher-using-python-could-use-a-little-help)

```
def affine (a, b):
    for i in range(26):
        print chr(i+65) + ": " + chr (((a*i+b)%26)+65)
```

This is something I have come across. How can I use this with a message "Hello world" and encrypt it?

And also how to Decrypt a message?

Comment: Since when were massages encrypted? :x

Comment: well sorry mate i today only kept my hands on python and my lecturer want me to learn this by the end of the day

Answer (score 0):

A readable, though extense, way of doing it is this:

```
   def encript(message, offset):
       result = ""
       for letter in message:
           if letter.isalpha():
               new_letter = chr(ord(letter) + offset)
               if (new_letter > "Z" and letter.isupper()) or (new_letter > "z" and letter.islower()):
                    new_letter = chr(ord(new_letter) - 26)
           else:
               new_letter = letter
           result += new_letter
        return result
```

a one liner version could be written thus:

```
>>> encript = lambda x, offset: "".join(chr(ord(le) + ((offset - (26 if (ord(le.upper()) + offset > ord("Z") )  else 0 ) ) if le.isalpha() else 0))  for le in x )
>>> encript("IBM 9000", -1)
'HAL 9000'
```

Comment: File "<pyshell#0>", line 11
    return result
                ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level this error is coming for me.....

Comment: hey can u please tell me y am i getting the error as above

Comment: Did you actually listen to anything you were told about the language so far? Read any reference material? Try writing any code? Putting in any effort at all?