# Inconsistent return types from python functions – Really?

Tags: python

I am new to Python, but not new to programming. To pick up on Python, I am going through an online introductory tutorial. I have worked through multiple examples of functions which return an inconsistent type of result, depending on arguments. E.G., the result may be an integer or a boolean, as in by_three() in this example:

```
def cube(number):
    return number**3

def by_three(number):
    if (number%3) == 0:
        return cube(number)
    else:
        return False
```

This sends up red flags to me. Is this acceptable practice in the Python world? Obviously the language allows it, it can be done, but should it be done?

Comment: I recently talked about this on a mailing list that I'm on. It's doable and in some circumstances, even done but I personally consider it an antipattern since the code that consumes this API will have to special case for each return type.

Comment: It's uncommon, and rightfully so.  In some cases it can make some sense, though.  For example, the regular expression match and search functions (in the `re` module) return a "match object" if the pattern matches the string, but return `None` if there's no match.  It so happens that this behavior seems more useful more often than, e.g., raising an exception if there's no match.  Depends on the problem!  `by_three()` is insane ;-)

Comment: I think its also worth mentioning that all methods in Python return the sentinel value (`None`) by default, this is also different from other languages.

Comment: If I had the reference material I'd put this as an answer. One of the phylosophies behind Python has always been: just because it is a bad idea does not mean the language should stop you from doing it. I think it is mentioned in "dive into python" as well.

Comment: @Leon - I think you are looking for [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=python%20consenting%20adults).

Comment: `False == 0` therefore the function is just wrong. Compare: `by_three(0) == by_three(1)`. It is a bad example. Could you use `filter()` function instead that returns a string if given a string, tuple for tuple, etc in Python 2 or `re.match()` example provided by @TimPeters.

Comment: That's the one, add it as the answer :)

Comment: here's [code example `caesar(plain_text)` function returns `bytes` if `plain_text` is `bytes` and it returns Unicode string (`str`) if input is Unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26371777/4279)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I take it back, that is not what I was looking for, but that approach is as good an answer as any

Comment: As others have said, returning `False` here is shoddy. OTOH, returning `None` is kind of tolerable. :) If you don't like this pattern in Python, you'd probably not be impressed by [Haskell's Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Maybe).

Comment: @TimPeters: Yes, `by_three()` is insane, as are many contrived examples. It is among many other contrived examples of function definition, syntax, and use. I have made no claim that I found a particularly good tutorial and I think I'm going to abandon it in favor of spelunking through (e)books about python.

Comment: @Leon: That link is beautiful. Put it together as an answer and I'll credit you. Thank you all for your comments. My takeaway is that, while useful, this is a practice which should be engaged judiciously. Including it in a tutorial example for python neophytes may indicate a poorly thought-out tutorial.

Comment: CuriousRabbit I think you may be referring to the link @BurhanKhalid added. I only mentioned a passing reference to the fact that "you can do what you want" because why should you be stopped :)

Comment: In 2 words: duck typing.

Comment: In some languages (say C), returning NULL or something is also inconsistant. The good pattern beeing returning a tuple with the validity check (say a BOOL), and the result next. The 2 in 1 permits by the language... well it's already an anti pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time thinking about why python "allows" inconsistent return types and realized it is not just python, but pretty much any OO language.

In python everything is an object, even class definitions are objects. As far as I remember the only thing that is not an object is the `type()` function.

So we can now assume that all types have a topmost super type that every other type inherits from. Like `Object` in Java. Which leads me to this hypothetical Java code example where you have a service tier querying a repository for users with a specific last name

```
Object getUsersByLastname(String lastname) {
    List<User> users = repository.getUsersByLastname(lastname);
    if (user.size() == 1) {
        return users.get(0);
    } else {
        return users;
    }
}
```

Anyone who has ever worked in Java will see this as a pretty poor piece of code. Whatever is calling this will always have to do type checking before continuing.

My opinion is that the Python example shown above is also poor code and that you will end with a maintenance nightmare. At the end of the day good design is something that is easy to maintain and does not require a ton of `if... else...` statements to work. It certainly feels like it break Open / Close principle in SOLID anyway, since at any time another return type can be added to that function and the calling code will need to be modified.

Just because you can do something does not mean you should.

Comment: The contract in your example is returning an `Object` which is almost everything except integer... So it doesn't break the contract. In the question it breaks the supposed contract.