# Python caesar cipher how to decode a specific sentence?

Tags: python, indexing, caesar-cipher, chr

I am trying to decode enciphered message `'lmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijk'`. I got that it shifted by 11 and I must decipher `'I wtvp olel decfnefcpd lyo lwrzctesxd'`.

Here's what I wrote so far:

```
#enciphered message = 'I wtvp olel decfnefcpd lyo lwrzctenter code hereesxd'

plain = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
#plain Index= 0123456789........25 

cipher = 'lmnopqrstuvwxxyzabcdefghijk'
#11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25...12345678910

cipher_text = input('Enter enciphered message: ')
clean_text ='I '
for i in cipher_text:
    if cipher_text.index(i) != " ":
        clean_text = clean_text + plain.index(cipher[(ord(i)-ord('a'))])
    else:
        clean_text = clean_text + " "

print(clean_text)
```

When I ran it:

```
Enter enciphered message: I wtvp olel decfnefcpd lyo lwrzctesxd
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-ac338a9d79fc> in <module>
     18 for i in cipher_text:
     19     if cipher_text.index(i) != " ":
---> 20         clean_text = clean_text + plain.index(cipher[(ord(i)-ord('a'))])
     21         #chr((cipher.index(cipher_text[i]))+ ord('a')) - 11)
     22     else:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

I am very new to Python, and I have no idea how to solve it.

add commend: The enciphered message that I want to decode has capital "I" as well as space between words, so I want to know how to decode capital and lowercase at the same time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caesar Cipher issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369035/caesar-cipher-issue)

Comment: @colidyre No, :(, I am very newbie in Python, so I do want to understand about it, I have no idea about def things. Honestly, I have no idea how to decode it, and it is not working. if you have any chance, and time, could you please look at the code I made, and give me some comment to make it work? :( Thanks.

Comment: @colidyre It also has capital "I" at the beginning of the sentence as well as space between words. :(

Answer (score 1):

`list.index()` returns the [index of that item's first occurence in the list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). So the expression `plain.index(cipher[(ord(i)-ord('a'))])` is an integer, which Python won't allow adding to a string.

What you probably want for the clean_text is the element in `plain` which has *that index*. So can use the standard `list[index]` notation to get the element: `plain[plain.index(...)]`

That line would now be:

```
clean_text = clean_text + plain[plain.index(cipher[(ord(i)-ord('a'))])]
```

```
>>> print(clean_text)
I wxxyzabcdefghhijlmnopqrstuv
```

---

Other changes/improvements:

1. For the line `if cipher_text.index(i) != " ":`, the expression will never be true since `list.index()` returns an integer, or a ValueError if not found, which will never match as equal to a space `" "`. You also already have the character you're checking in the loop variable `i`. So that could be:

   ```
   if i != " ":
   ```
2. There's a possible typo in `cipher` and `cipher_text`, the letter `x` appears twice.
3. Wrt your comment:

   > *It also has capital "I" at the beginning of the sentence as well as space between words. :(*

   That's from the line `clean_text ='I '` just before the loop. Change that to `clean_text =''`.
4. Don't concatenate strings with `x = x + 'something new'`. Keep appending each element to a list and then use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

   ```
   # before the loop:
   clean_text = []  # empty list
   # inside the loop:
   clean_text.append(plain[plain.index(cipher[(ord(i)-ord('a'))])])
   # later, after the loop, put:
   ''.join(clean_text)
   ```

Comment: Hi! I really appreciate your kind answer!, I tried again, but it still said 'IndexError: string index out of range' What happened to it :(, I am so sorry making you spend valuable time for me.

Comment: Oh! Now it is working, but not decode :( If you do not mind, can I ask you little bit more about it?

Comment: What I want to say in my comment, I wrote clean_text = 'I ' because I have no idea how to decode lowercase and uppercase at the same time. if you do not mind, could you provide me little more comments to make mine working properly? It is been a 7 days since I start learning Python :(, I really appreciate your help

Comment: That's because of `cipher` and `plain` not being the same length (because of the double 'x': `xx` in the `cipher`). So the index for 'y' will actually give you 'z' and for 'z' you get an error. (Join the Python chat room, I have a few minutes - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

Comment: Unfortunately, and sadly, I can't :( what it said ' You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.'

Comment: Thanks for trying!!! You are the best! One last question if possible!

Comment: After I removed double x, it gave me "I n hega zwpw opnqypqnao wjz whcknepdio" for the decode.. :( is there any other way to get the right decipher :(?

Comment: And is there any way to decipher capital and lowercase at the same time? I am sorry, I think that I have too many questions for you :(. If it bothers you, I am sorry

Comment: 1. To decipher upper or lower characters, use `j = i.lower()` and replace `ord(i)` with `ord(j)`. That way, you only look up the index based on its lower case version. The output will be lowercase only. 2. If you want to return the same as the input, give it a think on how to approach it. Feel free to ask a separate question on StackOverflow if it's for a different problem. Also, [give this a read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and welcome to SO.