# How do I replace a character in a list with a character in a different list in python

Tags: python

So I am trying to replace a character in a string with the next letter of the alphabet using strings. I have got the input converted but I  don't know what to do from here?
Here is my code:

```
alphabet =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
wordlist = []
inputword = input("Please enter a string")
wordlist = list(inputword)
for i in range(len(inputword)):

print (wordlist)
```

I am trying to get it so that if I inputted "Hello World" , it will return "Ifmmp xpsme"

It doesn't have to return the exact case (upper case letters can be returned as lower case

Comment: see my answer and let me know

Comment: What should `z` be replace with?

Comment: Perhaps, example of input and desired output would make things clear

Comment: alright done that

Comment: Apart from the fact that this question does not show any effort at all, a functional duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1538935/2564301

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to replace a character that is given by a user with the next character of the alphabet.

Assuming that `z` should become `a` use this:

### For single character inputs (e.g. 'a') use this:

```
alphabet =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
wordlist = []
inputword = input("Please enter a string:")
wordlist = list(inputword)

if wordlist[0] == 'z':
    #print('Sorry, I do not know what to do for this case')
    idx = 0
    new_word = alphabet[idx]
    print(new_word)

else:
    idx = alphabet.index(wordlist[0])
    new_word = alphabet[idx +1]
    print(new_word)
```

---

### For whole string inputs (e.g. 'hello world') use this:

```
def next_letter(st):
    index = 0
    new_word = ""
    alphapet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzacd"

    for i in st.lower():
        if i.islower(): #check if i s letter
            index = alphapet.index(i) + 1 #get the index of the following letter
            new_word += alphapet[index]    
        else: #if not letter
            new_word += i    
    return new_word

USER_INPUT = input('enter string:')

next_letter(USER_INPUT)
```

---

**Example:**

```
USER_INPUT= 'hello world'

print(next_letter(USER_INPUT))
'ifmmp xpsme'
```

Comment: What about `'z'` in the input?

Comment: see my answer. I commented this

Comment: Ok so that works for 1 position, what am I supposed to do for the whole string? As I didn't want a single character, it should work for a sentence

Comment: oh. do you want to replace each character in a string with the next one ? so the input is a whole string and not a single character ?

Comment: And for Z, could    if wordlist[0] == 'z':      new_word = 'a'

Comment: @RandexGrandma see my edit 1. for 'hello world' it works fine